# background tileMode="repeat" shows whitespace

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background

so i'm trying to apply a repeated tile background to my layout but when it displays it shows white space in between the tiles :/ is there any way to get rid of this ? [this is how it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWM3e.jpg)

background_repeat

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@mipmap/texture_tile_old"
android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/note_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_repeat"
android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Comment: try with different layout. still getting white space?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I still get the white space with any layout I use. I've tried different layouts, different images, nothing seems to work :/

Comment: in that case i think there is something wrong with your image files

Comment: are you using jpg or png image files?

Comment: it turned out to be the image, or at least how i was importing the image. silly mistake on my end, thank you so much :)

Comment: Well, I'm glad that your problem solved